# SQL Query Join queries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 queries in big query where i want to join 2 tables in some condition.

First query

[image: First query]

Second query is same but im using JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

Can anyone explain me why LEFT JOIN with WHERE condition returns diffrent results count then INNER JOIN?

Comment: Please put your queries in question as text and not as an image.

Comment: Isn't it a nested `select`? So, I think it's actually syntactically correct @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 3):

> why LEFT JOIN with WHERE condition returns diffrent results count then INNER JOIN?

- They are considering different starting sets to work with. Here are some nice illustrations on difference between joins:

  - https://www.diffen.com/difference/Inner_Join_vs_Outer_Join
  - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins
- Relevant images from referenced urls are here:
  [image]
  [image]
- note that OUTER is optional so left outer join is equal to left join

Comment: While this might be answering the question it is not recommended to put images as an Answer. It would be great if you can put all queries in Text instead of Image

Comment: Noted and make sence, but, all relevant queries are given in second referenced url. Illustrations are just given just as pointer to relevant parts for immediate answer and taken from first referenced url as such.

Comment: Having the queries as text might be nice, though for people who are confused about joins, Venn diagrams are probably the best way to visualize what each join type does.